# How to get windows service credentials

Tags: c#, windows-services

What I want to do is get the service's account credentials and use them in an ftp request. I haven't found anything that gives me the credentials. Is this even possible?

If there isn't anything that just gives me the log on credentials, I have used the following code to get the username. Is there a way to get useful credentials from just the username?

```
System.Management.SelectQuery sQuery = new System.Management.SelectQuery(string.Format("select * from Win32_Service where name = '[SERVICENAME]'")); 
using (System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher mgmtSearcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(sQuery))
{
    foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject service in mgmtSearcher.Get())
    {
        string servicelogondetails =
            string.Format("Name: {0} ,  Logon : {1} ", service["Name"].ToString(), service["startname"]).ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(servicelogondetails);
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about what a security problem this would be if it were possible.  If you want to use the service's credentials, have the service launch your application.

Comment: I am trying to ftp from the service. But I still need to provide credentials.

Comment: Simply not possible. Would be a massive security hole.

Comment: Some FTP servers support domain authentication, in which case you don't explicitly send the credentials.

Comment: If the remote credentials are the same as the credentials of the service account (and stored in the SCM's database) then in principle this is possible.  Not easily, though.  One solution would be to implement a [credential manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374792%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but note that this is a job for an expert; any mistakes in the code could have severe security implications.

Comment: It would be preferable to make the FTP password different to the account password, and store the FTP password yourself.